Losing precision when casting float to double, even for values that have precise binary representations
The canonical example used for explaining the binary vs decimal representation of floating points is the value 0.3:
float asFloat = 0.3;    // <-- 0.300000012
double asDouble = 0.3;  // <-- 0.29999999999999999
double asCastedDouble = static_cast<double>( asFloat );  // <-- 0.30000001192092896

asFloat and asDouble are the closest possible binary representation possible of the literal 0.3.  A naïve look might be surprised at the value of asCastedDouble, but then we remember that it’s the closest representation of the float value, not of the literal, so that makes sense.  I do wonder, however, why the casted double representation is not identical to the float representation (which is already in binary) with added zero bits in the mantissa, which in decimal would translate to 0.300000011200000000, but that is a separate question.
Consider now a second example for a different literal:
float asFloat2 = -0.488730401;    // <-- -0.488730401 
double asDouble2 = -0.488730401;  // <-- -0.48873040099999998
double asCastedDouble2 = static_cast<double>( asFloat2 );   // <-- -0.48873040080070496

This literal happens to be accurately representable in binary, hence asFloat2 is the same as our literal value.  Just like in the last example, I wonder why asDouble2 is “less” accurate than asFloat2 instead of being identical with extra zero bits in the mantissa, but I’ll let it slide.
The question is now: why is asCastedDouble2 the value that it is? It is not the same setup as the previous example, as in there we had a precision error introduced in the float, which was then carried into the double.  In this case, however, the float value is identical to the literal, so where does the value of as asCastedDouble2 come from?  It is clearly not the closest binary representation possible, since asDouble2 shows us a closer representation?
So I guess my question is twofold:

why can certain numbers representible as a float not be representible as a double?
probably related, why does it appear like we lose precision when converting from float to double?


I can promise you that -0.488730401 is not precisely representable as a float. Just because it prints the same does not mean that it is accurately represented

For confirmation see this site

To answer the first question, there are no exact floats that cannot also be exactly represented as doubles. Doubles have more digits in the mantissa and exponent.

Your misunderstanding seems to come from the belief that when you print a floating point number at maximum precision you are seeing a number that equals the actual floating point number. That is not true.

@john with the possible exceptions of some powers of two ;) (both with positive and negative exponents) (https://godbolt.org/z/M4f9M948v)

@PepijnKramer I must be missing something

Powers of two have exact representations (up to some limits) ;) But they are the exception (I added a godbolt link)

@PepijnKramer I know I'm using a double negative which might not translate well, but I think what I said is logically correct and your examples are not exceptions to that.

To put it another (less confusing) way, all exact floats also have exact representations as doubles.

@john Yup ;) .  But for OP in general just NEVER compare floating point numbers for equality (floats or doubles)

To work through the example you gave -0.488730401 (decimal) converts as a float to -0.01111101000111010111 (binary). The exact value of that in decimal is -0.48873043060302734375

Try converting -0.488730401 e.g. at https://www.exploringbinary.com/binary-converter/ – you'll notice that there are fare more digits than the 24 float can hold...

"The canonical example used for explaining the binary vs decimal representation of floating points is the value 0.3:" -- I thought the typical example was 0.1. I didn't know there was a canon to this.

Minor point: double asCastedDouble = static_cast<double>( asFloat ); can be written as double asCastedDouble = asFloat;. The cast just tells the compiler to do the conversion that it would do anyway.

Counter-example: Compose the decimals as a sum only of powers of two, e.g. 0.015625 (1/64), 0.875 (0.5 + 0.25 + 0.125), … Exponent and mantissa of float must not be exceeded, of course...


I do wonder, however, why the casted double representation is not identical to the float representation

They are identical, you just don't print enough digits.
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    float asFloat = 0.3; 
    double asDouble = 0.3;
    double asCastedDouble = static_cast<double>( asFloat );
    std::cout << std::setprecision(1000);
    std::cout << asFloat << '\n';        // 0.300000011920928955078125
    std::cout << asDouble << '\n';       // 0.299999999999999988897769753748434595763683319091796875
    std::cout << asCastedDouble << '\n'; // 0.300000011920928955078125
}


Consider now a second example ... This literal happens to be accurately representable in binary

No it isn't. You're not printing enough digits.
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    float asFloat = -0.488730401; 
    double asDouble = -0.488730401;
    double asCastedDouble = static_cast<double>( asFloat );
    std::cout << std::setprecision(1000);
    std::cout << asFloat << '\n';        // -0.4887304008007049560546875
    std::cout << asDouble << '\n';       // -0.4887304009999999809821247254149056971073150634765625
    std::cout << asCastedDouble << '\n'; // -0.4887304008007049560546875
}


I knew that printing numbers had rounding issues, that's why I got the values straight from the debugger.  Today I learned that the debugger also has its own set of rounding rules, which obscured these equalities from me.

@Blabba I wonder if there's a setting for this. Normally you don't want to see all those digits, so I'm not surprised it's rounded by default.

There are no numbers representable as a float that are not representable as a double.
You are confusing the usual rounded printed output in decimal and the actual number represented inside the machine. To display the 32 bit float "0.3" accurately in decimal form requires a lot of decimal digits. Enough decimal digits to display 1/2^24 exactly.
See for example IEEE 754 Base converter where you can put your chosen number in and see both representations in 32 bit float and 64 bit double (exact decimal, hex and binary).
Float promotion to double faithfully zero pads the mantissa up to 53 bits and extends the range of the exponent from +/-127 to +/-1023.
